# React Native or React. Validate inputs

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-state

I have three inputs in the form. When I submit the form, I want to check, if this inputs are not empty. But after submitting empty form only last input has error style. I want all three inputs to have error style.
My code:

```
const [name, setName] = useState(null)
const [email, setEmail] = useState(null)
const [message, setMessage] = useState(null)

const [style, setStyle] = useState({
    name : null,
    email : null,
    message : null,
    
})

const sendEmail = async () => {

    setStyle({
        ...style,
        name: null,
        email: null,
        message: null
    })
        
        if(!name || !email || !message){ 
            if(!name) {
                setStyle({
                    ...style, 
                    name: gStyle.inputError
                })
            }
            if(!email) {
                setStyle({
                    ...style, 
                    email: gStyle.inputError
                })
            }  
            if(!message) {
                setStyle({
                    ...style, 
                    message: gStyle.inputError
                })
            }                
        }
        
        else {/*do smth*/}
    }        
}
```

And here is my view in compo:

```
<View>
     <TextInput onChangeText={(value) => {setName(value)}} />
     <TextInput onChangeText={(value) => {setEmail(value)}} />
     <TextInput onChangeText={(value) => {setMessage(value)}} />
                        
     <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => sendEmail()}>
         <Text>Send</Text>
     </TouchableOpacity>
</View>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of setting state at every if condition, create an empty style obj in sendEmail function , push error style at every condition in the style obj.
Like

```
const errorStyles={};
 if(condition)
errorStyles.name=gStyles.error;
```

At last set styles state with the errorStyles obj
Like

```
setStyle(errorStyles);
```

Try that and see if it works .Other then that where are the styles being applied on the text input ?

Comment: Works. Thanks! 
In my project inputs have styles. Just forgot to add them in this simple example